# pandas group By select columns

Tags: pandas, group-by

I work with Cloudera VM 5.2.0 pandas 0.18.0.

I have the following data

```
adclicksDF = pd.read_csv('/home/cloudera/Eglence/ad-clicks.csv',
               parse_dates=['timestamp'],
       skipinitialspace=True).assign(adCount=1)

adclicksDF.head(n=5)
Out[65]: 
            timestamp  txId  userSessionId  teamId  userId  adId   adCategory  \
0 2016-05-26 15:13:22  5974           5809      27     611     2  electronics   
1 2016-05-26 15:17:24  5976           5705      18    1874    21       movies   
2 2016-05-26 15:22:52  5978           5791      53    2139    25    computers   
3 2016-05-26 15:22:57  5973           5756      63     212    10      fashion   
4 2016-05-26 15:22:58  5980           5920       9    1027    20     clothing   

   adCount  
0        1  
1        1  
2        1  
3        1  
4        1
```

I want to do a group by for the field timestamp

```
adCategoryclicks = adclicksDF[['timestamp','adId','adCategory','userId','adCount']]

agrupadoDF = adCategoryclicks.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='1H'))['adCount'].agg(['count','sum'])

agrupadoDF.head(n=5)     
Out[68]: 
                     count  sum
timestamp                      
2016-05-26 15:00:00     14   14
2016-05-26 16:00:00     24   24
2016-05-26 17:00:00     13   13
2016-05-26 18:00:00     16   16
2016-05-26 19:00:00     16   16
```

I want to add to agrupado more columns adCategory, idUser .
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple values in `userId` and `adCategory` for each `group`, so aggreagate by `join`:

*In this sample last two datetime are changed for better output*

```
print (adclicksDF)
            timestamp  txId  userSessionId  teamId userId  adId   adCategory  \
0 2016-05-26 15:13:22  5974           5809      27    611     2  electronics   
1 2016-05-26 15:17:24  5976           5705      18   1874    21       movies   
2 2016-05-26 15:22:52  5978           5791      53   2139    25    computers   
3 2016-05-26 16:22:57  5973           5756      63    212    10      fashion   
4 2016-05-26 16:22:58  5980           5920       9   1027    20     clothing   

   adCount  
0        1  
1        1  
2        1  
3        1  
4        1
```

```
#cast int to string
adclicksDF['userId'] = adclicksDF['userId'].astype(str)
adCategoryclicks = adclicksDF[['timestamp','adId','adCategory','userId','adCount']]


agrupadoDF = adCategoryclicks.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='1H'))
                             .agg({'adCount': ['count','sum'], 
                                   'userId': ', '.join,
                                   'adCategory': ', '.join})

agrupadoDF.columns = ['adCategory','count','sum','userId']

print (agrupadoDF)
                                         adCategory  count  sum  \
timestamp                                                         
2016-05-26 15:00:00  electronics, movies, computers      3    3   
2016-05-26 16:00:00               fashion, clothing      2    2   

                              userId  
timestamp                             
2016-05-26 15:00:00  611, 1874, 2139  
2016-05-26 16:00:00        212, 1027
```